# Is it possible to make conf value of airflow dag readable?

Tags: postgresql, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to read conf value of dag in Apache Airflow.
It turns out value is stored in some unreadable format.

How can I decode it?

What I have already tried:

```
airflow=# select conf from dag_run limit 1;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 conf
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \x800495c6000000000000007d94288c0c70726f6a6563745f6e616d65948c0970726f6a6563742d32948c166368616e67655f696e5f6c6162656c5f636f6e66696794888c1069735f64656661756c745f6d6f64656c94898c0a656d62656464696e6773948c4a7b226e616d65223a2022676c6f76655f31303064222c202276657273696f6e223a2022676c6f76655f313030645f656e5f322e342e305f322e345f31353739363930313034303332227d948c097365727665725f6964944b028c0c6465706c6f795f6d6f64656c9488752e
(1 row)

airflow=# select encode(conf, 'escape') from dag_run limit 1;
                                                                                 encode
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \200\x04\225\306\000\000\000\000\000\000\000}\224(\214\x0Cproject_name\224\214  project-2\224\214\x16change_in_label_config\224\210\214\x10is_default_model\224\211\214+
 embeddings\224\214J{"name": "glove_100d", "version": "glove_100d_en_2.4.0_2.4_1579690104032"}\224\214   server_id\224K\x02\214\x0Cdeploy_model\224\210u.
(1 row)
```

`encode(conf, 'escape')` has made it a little bit more readable. But still not completely. How can I make it completely readable ?

Note: Answer doesn't have to a pure SQL query. We are free to use python too if necessary.

Comment: read from where? The DAG has access to it's own conf why would you need to query it using SQL?

Comment: Read from psql table `dag_run` just like it is possible to read `xcom` from psql table. Is it possible or not ?

Comment: All I need to know is if it is possible to decode `conf` column of `dag_run` table, because we can decode `value` column of `xcom` with `select encode(value, 'escape') from xcom;`. If this is not possible, I will have to insert data into `xcom` too. Then I can read easily from xcom. I just don't want to put the same stuff in two places. I already have access to encoded data. Would be great if we could decode that into plain string. @Elad